# How do I make a for in loop that actually loops through all the elements

Tags: swift, for-loop, swift2

I Am trying to build a very simple app:

It will print elements of an array so here are my two questions

in my current code

```
@IBOutlet weak var moussarLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func moussarButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var moussar = ["dzv","avazv","sdv dv","dvar3"]

    for var i = 0; i<moussar.count; i++ {            
        moussarLabel.text = "\(moussar[i])"
    }
}
```

I want to know two things:

1. when the code executes it automatically print the last element of the array without displaying the other elements
2. Say that I want the text in the array to be much much longer, how do i make UILabel to adapt to the text and to allow the user to scroll though the text?

thanks for the help

Comment: The code is looping through the entire array. But the label will only display the last value you set.

Comment: to get the last element do: `moussar[moussar.count-1]`

Comment: @WilliamKinaan it would be much easier to use moussar.last

Answer (score 0):

1. The final element in the array is the last thing the loop assigns to the text label. Sounds like its working as expected. Did you mean to concatenate (add) the strings?
2. You can do that with a UITextView https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/

Comment: i want to be able that every time I press the button that it prints some element of the array ;;;

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't scroll a UILabel so you'll have to use a `UITextField`. Read the documentation for details, it shouldn't be too hard when only displaying a single word. For getting the last element of the array, use `moussarLabel.last` which returns an optional. As the text property of a text view or a label, respectively, accepts `nil` as value, this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the array scoped to the class and not the function. In addition a counter variable can be used to access different elements.

To make the text scrollable you can use a `UITextView`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var moussarLabel: UITextView!

var moussar = ["dzv","avazv","sdv dv","dvar3"]
var moussarIndex = 0

@IBAction func moussarButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    moussarLabel.text = "\(moussar[moussarIndex++])"

    // if you want to cycle through the array use the following condition
    if moussarIndex >= moussar.count {
        moussarIndex = 0
    }
}
```